# Drone Feedback: Object Detection / Color Detection? Is there way just to isolate detection on a specific object

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ar.drone

[image: Tracking Picture]I have been working on a code where an A.R Drone 2.0 will detect color and put a red dot in the middle of the image. I am using streaming for the drone. The goal is for the drone to detect a white gutter and fly straight over it from one point to the other. Essentially following a line. I noticed when I changed the BGR to 0, 0, 255, I get the entire gutter to be distinguished but it detects white spots as well. Is there to isolate my detection just to see the gutter. Maybe using shapes, once the gutter is detected, put a bounding box. And my finally question is how do I tell my drone to follow the red dot or maybe drawing a line. I looked at [`python-AR`](https://github.com/venthur/python-ardrone) drone libraries but don't know how to apply it.This is my code.

```
import numpy as np    
import cv2        


# open the camera    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')


def nothing(x):    
    pass

cv2.namedWindow('result')


# Starting with 100's to prevent error while masking    
h,s,v = 100,100,100            
# Creating track bar    
cv2.createTrackbar('h', 'result',0,179,nothing)    
cv2.createTrackbar('s', 'result',0,255,nothing)    
cv2.createTrackbar('v', 'result',0,255,nothing)    

while True:    
    #read the image from the camera    
    ret, frame = cap.read()            
    #You will need this later    
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, 35)    

    #converting to HSV

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)                   
    # get info from track bar and appy to result    
    h = cv2.getTrackbarPos('h','result')    
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos('s','result')    
    v = cv2.getTrackbarPos('v','result')

    # Normal masking algorithm    
    lower_blue = np.array([h,s,v])    
    upper_blue = np.array([180,255,255])        

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_blue, upper_blue)            
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask = mask)            
    cv2.imshow('result',result)            
    #find center    
    cnts=cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]            
    center=None        

    if len(cnts)>0:    
        c=max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)    
        ((x,y),radius)=cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)    
        M=cv2.moments(c)    
        center=(int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))            
        if radius>10:    
            #cv2.circle(frame, (int(x),int(y)), int(radius), 2)    
            cv2.circle(frame, center,5,(0,0,255),-1)

    # color detection limits    
    lB = 5    
    lG = 50    
    lR = 50    
    hB = 15    
    hG = 255    
    hR = 255    
    lowerLimits = np.array([lB, lG, lR])    
    upperLimits = np.array([hB, hG, hR])            
    # Our operations on the frame come here    
    thresholded = cv2.inRange(frame, lowerLimits, upperLimits)    
    outimage = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = thresholded)                    
    cv2.imshow('original', frame)            
    # Display the resulting frame    
    cv2.imshow('processed',outimage)


    # Quit the program when Q is pressed    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):    
         break       

# When everything done, release the capture    
print 'closing program'    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample input images? It is possible to isolate the noise, but I can't tell without seeing the sample feeds. if you could upload the pure video, that'd be great!

Comment: alright I will do that now and upload vieo. How can you save video stream to file BTW?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video

Comment: @Titanoboa, i added pictures as requested. I put leaves in the gutter for real time application. But yeah here you go. So now, how do i detect two colors white and (brown-black). and the outside noise, how do i make a box or something around gutter

Comment: Is this the output that you want? https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgzCh.jpg

Comment: i see you removed the background from the picture. Thats great. but from the picture the red dot is all the way at the end where white is detected. Any way I can detect both those colors in the gutter(white, color of leaves)and somehow bound a box just on that area.

Comment: Just the gutter, yes. You can use `cv2.erode` to eliminate the small dots near the center of mass. Detecting the area with the leaves though, that's very very difficult and even if you'd come up with a simple method with contour properties / color properties etc, it'd be ad-hoc and be immediately rendered useless by a change in light intensities. If I do come up with something though, I'll be sure to post it here.

Comment: can you post the part of code on how to apply cv2.erode? @Titanoboa

Comment: @Titanoboa  Please when you get chance can you do it? But also I am trying just to see the gutter, how do I lock in on one object, lets say I feel around the room and I just want to see the gutter nothing else.